# How to use Jquery to change div css/scss on a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass

I am a jquery beginner. I'm trying to make a dropdown menu where when the user clicks one of the buttons it will link to its correct section. Before a user clicks a button, all sections must be hidden (`display: none`), but when an option is selected from the dropdown, I want to use js/jquery to trigger a css change in the section div to appear (`display: block`). Pretty lost and I can't seem to get the jquery to work, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#departments a').on('click',function()) {
        $(this).css({'display','block'});
  });
}
```

```css
article.apply {
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
}
article.apply  p {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
article.apply  div.math {
  display: none;
}
article.apply  div.cmsc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
   <a id= "selectedDept" class="dropbtn button button-red 
                        caret"> Search </a>
      <div id = "departments" class="dropdown-content">
         <a class= "dept" href="#math">MATH</a>
         <a class= "dept" href="#cmsc">CMSC</a>
       </div>
</div>

<article class="apply">
   <div class=“math”>
      <h2> Hello World </h2>
   </div>
   <div class=“cmsc”>
      <h2> Hello World! </h2>
   </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Tangential to your question I'd like to draw your attention to https://api.jquery.com/hide/ and https://api.jquery.com/show/ because there is no reason to use `css()` for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see with the console on your snippet code your Javascript was very wrong:

- You forgot to close the last `)` (of the `ready()` function)
- You close the function `.on()` before the `{}` of the callback
- You update the css with `{'display','block'}` instead of `{'display': 'block'}`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#departments a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({'display':'block'});
  });
});
```

```css
article.apply {
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
}
article.apply  p {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
article.apply  div.math {
  display: none;
}
article.apply  div.cmsc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
   <a id= "selectedDept" class="dropbtn button button-red caret"> Search </a>
      <div id = "departments" class="dropdown-content">
         <a class= "dept" href="#math">MATH</a>
         <a class= "dept" href="#cmsc">CMSC</a>
       </div>
</div>

<article class="apply">
   <div class=“math”>
      <h2> Hello World </h2>
   </div>
   <div class=“cmsc”>
      <h2> Hello World! </h2>
   </div>
</article>
```